# How to catch RestKit internal errors?

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit, restkit-0.20

I get the following error when using RestKit:

```
error=Error Domain=org.restkit.RestKit.ErrorDomain Code=-1017 "Loaded an unprocessable response (200) with content type 'application/json'" UserInfo=0x1f08d9c0 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://dev.hopon.co.il/v1/travels.json, NSUnderlyingError=0x1f0a1540 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)", NSLocalizedDescription=Loaded an unprocessable response (200) with content type 'application/json'}
```

It clearly states what is causing the error, and I understand that. My question is how can I catch&handle this error in my code? (as the failure block isn't called)

Comment: Which method are you calling which results in this error and is this a development error or a production error (i.e. a coding error or something which could actually go wrong during usage)?

Comment: I'm calling 'postObject:path:parameters:success:failure:'. And yes, this could potentially happen in production as well.